# How to Reference Bootstrap-Colorpicker in ASP Net 5 View

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm working through the ASP.NET MVC 6 tutorials and getting used to the framework. I have a requirement to add a color picker to one of my views. Since the HTML5 type 'color' isn't supported on IE I can't use that.

Instead I thought I'd use the *bootstrap-colorpicker* plugin here: http://mjolnic.com/bootstrap-colorpicker/.

I've installed the package via NPM but can't work out how to reference it in the `View`. Should the package be installing files in the `wwwroot\libs` folder? Or do I need to copy these in manually and reference in the `@section Scripts`?

I've also installed it using NuGet PM and it appears under `References` but I'm in the same boat wondering how to reference it in the actual `View`.

Comment: drag the `js` and `css` file to your view.

Comment: Where from? I can't see the file anywhere in the `wwwroot`. My source files have a 'node_modules' folder (which contains the colorpicker) but I can't see how this is accessed in Visual Studio.

Comment: Check [this blog post](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/283/asp-net-5-managing-client-side-dependencies-with-npm-bower-and-gulp), hopefully it will help you to find your installed package.

Comment: is there any folder created inside `www\lib` after you have added those libraries.

Comment: No there isn't - But following the blog @Michael suggested I can view all files and see the node_modules in the solution explorer. I can then drag a link onto the View resulting in: `<script src="~/node_modules/bootstrap-colorpicker/dist/js/bootstrap-colorpicker.js"></script>`.

Comment: that's what you need to do . Now It should work.

Answer (score 0):

The installation with NuGet PM creates following folder structure:

```
/Content
    /bootstrap-colorpicker
        /css
            /bootstrap-colorpicker.css
        /img
            /*.png
/Scripts
    /bootstrap-colorpicker.js
```

So you have to add following lines to BundleConfig:

```
bundles.Add(New ScriptBundle("~/bundles/colorscripts").Include(
    "~/Scripts/bootstrap-colorpicker.js")
bundles.Add(New StyleBundle("~/Content/bootstrap-colorpicker/bootstrap-colorpicker/colorstyle").Include(
    "~/Content/bootstrap-colorpicker/css/bootstrap-colorpicker.css"))
```

Then reference the bundles in the Razor view:

```
@section SiteCSS
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/bootstrap-colorpicker/bootstrap-colorpicker/colorstyle")
End Section

@section Scripts
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/colorscripts")
End Section
```

BTW: The additional "bootstrap-colorpicker" folder for the style bundle is necessary for the optimizer. Otherwise you get a 404 (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11386982/3620572), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20484188/3620572) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25805302/3620572)).