# CSS changing after publish

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, publishing, deploying

We are having a weird problem when publishing an asp.net MVC project.
After publishing in Release mode, this CSS:

```
.appTitle {
    font-size: calc(1vw + 1vh - .1vmin) !important;
}
```

becomes this:

```
.appTitle {
    font-size: calc(1vw+ 1vh- .1vmin) !important;
}
```

The difference is in the spacing before the '+' and '-' signs. This absence of spaces is making the style not apply.

This does not happen when publishing in Debug mode.

The strange thing is, we have another project with almost identical CSS that does not do this when publishing.

So my question is: why is this happening, and what can I do to avoid it?

Comment: Some plugin is possibly minifying your CSS when you compile in release mode?

Comment: try clean solution, rebuild  and publish again into a new location

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24823259/css-js-bundle-in-single-file-in-mvc-when-publish-with-release-option?rq=1 Guess this post will help you.. Check out!

Comment: @Zack I thought about that, but the CSS on the other site is getting minified as well.

Comment: @Aravind tried what you said, no luck

Comment: @Aravind I looked at that post and tried the only suggestion that seemed like it would work and it didn't change anything.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124466/discussion-between-aravind-and-hashtagnatty).

Comment: is this CSS included via a bundle?

Comment: @NeilN Yes, this is included via a bundle.

Comment: The bundling process is probably the issue. You will likely have to include this CSS file directly or put this particular style in-line.

Comment: @NeilN I was thinking that, but do you know why it does this? Is there some feature I can turn off in order to avoid it? The other site I mention above is bundled in the same fashion, yet it does not have this problem. I am going to try and mess with the bundle, see if changing the order in which the .CSS files are bundled will change anything.